# Why would we use a Key Agreement Protocol if we already have a key between 2 entities?

Tags: keys, protocol-analysis

For example in my course there is this **protocol** :

Initialisation: A and B are sharing a symmetric key S.
(1) **A -> B: Ra** ; A generates a random number and sends it to A
(2) **A <- B: Rb** ; B does the same
A and B computes the session key **K := E_S(Ra XOR Rb)**.

Why A and B would establish a new key **K** if they already have the key **S** ?
I don't get it.

For me, the **Diffie-Hellman protocol** is coherent because it establishes a key between 2 entities that have never talked before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Hint

Consider what would happen if an adversary somehow managed to recover the session key.

### Spoiler

If they simply used the shared key as the session key directly, then an adversary who compromises the key can then compromise all future communications.

If they derive the session key using the shared key, then an adversary who compromises the session key only compromises the current session.

### Why not just use DH?

There are plenty of reasons - the first is probably to demonstrate the point above.

Secondly, DH is more computationally expensive then the pre-shared key technique.

- Some real world protocols do in fact offer the ability to secure a communications channel via pre-shared keys.
- A constrained device may not be able to afford the circuit size/power/time/bandwidth to use DH